# Python Agglomerative Clustering : finding the closest points in clusters

Tags: python, hierarchical-clustering

The linkage matrix for clustering provides the cluster index, and distance
for each step of the clustering hierarchy. 
When two clusters are merged, I would like to know which two points were the closest in the clusters. I am using the metric "single" i.e. closest distance

I know I can do this trivially by an exhaustive search and comparison. Is the information already there after linkage ? Is there a smarter way to get this information?

Comment: Welcome to SO. What code, libraries, and example data are you using?  Please see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your questions:

- No, this information is not available after linkage, at least according to the official Python documentation.
- The **closest pair of points problem** is a problem of computational geometry, and can be solved in logarithmic time by a recursive *divide and conquer* algorithm (note that exhaustive search is quadratic). See this Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem) for more information. Check also this [paper](http://euro.ecom.cmu.edu/people/faculty/mshamos/1975ClosestPoint.pdf) by Shamos and Hoey. Note that the original formulation of the problem involves only one set of points. However, adaptation for two sets is straightforward; you might find this [discussion](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2415/shortest-distance-between-a-point-in-a-and-a-point-in-b) helpful.